# Getting image from resource file. Create general function to retrieve resources

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I have a DLL, that stores the images for our project.(C# 4.0, VS2010).
In the DLL there is a resource file, I'm using -

```
public Image Get1()
{
   return DM.DMReourceLib._1; 
}
```

in order to access the image _1. This way I'll end up writing 1200 get's functions, one for each image.
I'm looking for a way to do

```
public Image GetImage(string name)
{
   return DM.DMresourceLib.name;
}
```

10x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look how designer class was generated. Maybe it can help you:

```
internal static System.Drawing.Bitmap price {
        get {
            object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("price", resourceCulture);
            return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep. Great Learning stuff. I just did it the same way. 10x

Answer (score 1):

```
var field = typeof(DM.DMresourceLib).GetField(name);
return (Image)field.GetValue(DM.DMresourceLib);
```

...or something like that. (If those are properties use `GetProperty` of course)

Comment: I don't have a GetType() function.

Comment: Every [object has a GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) method.

Comment: There is GetType in var field = DM.DMresourceLib.ResourceManager.GetType().GetField(name); but I get null.

Comment: I'll fix my code, i suppose `DMresourceLib` is not an object but a class. **Edit:** Done.

Answer (score 1):

```
Image ImageFromResource = (Image) Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("RecordImage");
```

Please write the Namespace while posting code. Even what reference to add, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use Reflection:

```
public Image GetImage(string name) 
{   
    var field = DM.DMresourceLib.GetType().GetField(name);             

    return (Image)field.GetValue(DM.DMresourceLib); 
}
```

Comment: The binding flags overload is not needed in this case.

Comment: @H.B. I've always used this overload. But I read the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53seyfee.aspx) due to your comment and without the BindingFlags it will return any public instance OR static field. Thanks for that! Updating example code (to remove BindingFlags from GetField method call).

Comment: You're welcome! And now your code is the exact same as mine :P

Comment: @H.B. Yeah - I noticed that too :D.  It wasn't originally (and I didn't copy!). Note to OP: You should accept H.B.'s answer as he got to it 1st and had the most correct code.